Vlookup and index(match) only picks one value
I have 3 worksheets, {Sales, Members, Payments}. I am doing my sales and then for the transaction select Member A with a sales price say 100 and 300 (Member is cell B4 and Price is Cell D4 on SALES worksheet). The transactions is calculated to MEMBER sheet D3 with a sumifs, index and match formula
=(SUMIFS(Sales!$D$4:$D$9,Sales!$B$4:$B$9,Members!B3)

.
Now on the payments sheet I want to enter multiple payments for member A and member B, which then needs to be deducted from !MEMBERS D3 & D4 but the problem is is that vlookup and index(match()) only select one value and not multiple values, so the update value is wrong..
=(SUMIFS(Sales!$D$4:$D$9,Sales!$B$4:$B$9,Members!B3)-    INDEX(Payments!$B$3:$B$5,MATCH(Members!B3,Payments!$A$3:$A$9,1))))
What I am trying to achieve is that D4 on !MEMBERS D4 should be updated according to the lookup value of member A from Sales MINUS payments for MEMBER A (multiple payments).

Lookup returns the first found matching value. If you have a newer Excel switch to FILTER, else use a combination of INDEX/AGGREGATE

It would seem that you are looking to subtract the sum of the payments from the sum of the sales which suggests using SUMIFS in both instances. =SUMIFS(Sales!$D$4:$D$9,Sales!$B$4:$B$9,Members!B3)- SUMIFS(Payments!B$3:B$6,Payments!A$3:A$6,Members!B3)

Could you try this by defining tables? By using tables you don't need to adjust ranges manually later.

Create tables for Members, Sales and Payments by naming columns with unique titles.
Clear exisiting content from calculated cells in Members table.
Enter calculated fields for your needs using either SUMIF or FILTER if you have Microsoft 365.

Members



Member
Total Sales
Total Payments
Remaining




MemberA
=IFERROR(SUMIF(Sales[Member],[@Member],Sales[Sale]),0)
=IFERROR(SUMIF(Payments[Member],[@Member],Payments[Amount]),0)
=[@[Total  Sales]]-[@[Total Payments]]


Or






=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(Sales[Sale],Sales[Member]=[@Member])),0)
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(Payments[Amount],Payments[Member]=[@Member])),0)




Payments



Member
Amount




MemberA
100


MemberB
50


MemberA
50


MemberB
300



Sales



Member
Sale
Category




MemberA
50



MemberB
100



MemberC
150



MemberA
300



MemberB
400



MemberC
500




Members



Member
Total Sales
Total Payments
Remaining




MemberA
350
150
200


MemberB
500
350
150


MemberC
650
0
650



